# Passing . . . to `map()` using tidyeval

Tags: r, function, purrr, tidyeval

I want to pass dots `...` to my `map()` using a quosure so I can evaluate the argument provided.

Passing `...` directly works, but quoting `...` and splicing using `!!!` causes an error.

I've tried using the various rlang functions i.e. `syms`, `quos`, `enquos`, etc. I've done my best to read through Advanced-R Chapters 17-20.

I've created a function `f` which draws from a random normal distribution for every number up until `n`. I can pass other parameters to `rnorm()` using the dots. This works fine.

```r
library(magrittr)
library(purrr)


f <- function(n, ...) {
1:n %>% 
  map(rnorm, ...)
}


f(2, mean = 10)
#> 
#> [[1]]
#> [1] 10.90561
#> 
#> [[2]]
#> [1] 11.19031 12.16856
f(2)
#> [[1]]
#> [1] -1.197873
#> 
#> [[2]]
#> [1]  1.023398 -2.023645
```

I've created a second function `g()` which is intended to do the same thing but using tidy eval.

```r
g <- function(n, ...) {

  1:n %>% 
    map(rnorm, !!!enquos(...))
}

g(3)

#> 
#> [[1]]
#> [1] NA
#> 
#> [[2]]
#> [1] NA NA
#>
#> Warning messages:
#> 1: In .f(.x[[i]], ...) : NAs produced
#> 2: In .f(.x[[i]], ...) : NAs produced
```

This implementation produces `NA`.

I've tried using `list2()` for this but still am unable to get it to evaluate. Is there a way to evaluate the dots using tidyeval within a map call?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no way to do this with `purrr::map()`. The dots are passed to the mapped function as is, without any changes. So it is the responsibility of the mapped function to implement tidy dots by capturing `...` with `enquos()` or `list2()`.

What you could do is create your own mapping function that takes dots with `!!!` support, creates a call with the arguments spliced in, and maps that call over the inputs:

```
map_splice <- function(.x, .f, ...) {
  n <- length(.x)
  out <- vector("list", n)

  # Capture arguments with `!!!` support
  args <- list2(...)

  # Create call with arguments spliced in
  call <- expr(.f(.x[[i]], !!!args))

  for (i in seq_len(n)) {
    out[[i]] <- eval(call)
  }

  out
}

h <- function(n, ...) {
  map_splice(seq_len(n), rnorm, ...)
}

h(3)
#> [[1]]
#> [1] 0.198766
#>
#> [[2]]
#> [1]  0.99824414 -0.08231719
#>
#> [[3]]
#> [1]  0.5288825 -0.6098536  0.7858720

args <- list(mean = 50, sd = 3)
h(3, !!!args)
#> [[1]]
#> [1] 49.32423
#>
#> [[2]]
#> [1] 57.51101 46.69594
#>
#> [[3]]
#> [1] 53.80943 50.00880 54.96616
```